# Scrapy vs Javascript Pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, scrapy

**Edit:**

I managed to make some progress by using Scrapy's FormRequest and are now looking to understand how to iterate through all pages. Unfortunately, the following code only returns the contents for page 209:

```
for i in range (1, 210):
        formdata = {'pageNumber': str(i)}

        def parse(self, response):

            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response, formdata=self.formdata, callback=self.after_post)

        def after_post(self, response):
            for link in response.css('div.AL'):
                yield{
                    'link': link.css('div.AL').extract()
                }
```

It looks like the loop for i runs it course before the 'def parse(self, response)' part takes place (i.e. i runs up to 209 before moving on). Any idea on how to structure the iteration and get this working would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Original post:**

I am trying to crawl a website with Scrapy but got stuck as the page displays the data inside a form and uses javascript for pagination.

This is the html part of the pagination:

```
    <div id="dvPager" class="AList-GridPagingArea">
            <div class="seperator20"></div>
            <div class="AList-GridPageStart" id="pagerFirst">First</div>
            <div class="AList-GridPagePrev" id="pagerPrevious">Previous</div>
            <div class="AList-GridPageCurrent">Page 1 of 211</div>
            <div class="AList-GridPageNext" id="pagerNext">Next</div>
            <div class="AList-GridPageEnd" id="pagerLast">Last</div>
            <div class="seperator20"></div>
        </div>

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PageNumber must be a 
number." data-val-required="The PageNumber field is required." 
id="pageNumber" name="pageNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

And here is the corresponding javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pagerFirst").bind('click', function(){GoToPage(1)});
            $("#pagerPrevious").bind('click', function(){GoToPage(1)});
            $("#pagerNext").bind('click', function(){GoToPage(2)});
            $("#pagerLast").bind('click', function(){GoToPage(211)});
            $('#pagerFirst, #pagerPrevious, #pagerNext, #pagerLast').hover(function() {
                $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
            });

            if(1 == 1 || 211 == 0){
                $("#pagerFirst").unbind('click');
                $('#pagerFirst').hover(function() {
                    $(this).css('cursor','default');
                });
            }
            if(1 == 1 || 211 == 0) {
                $("#pagerPrevious").unbind('click');
                $('#pagerPrevious').hover(function() {
                    $(this).css('cursor','default');
                });
            }
            if(1 == 211 || 211 == 0) {
                $("#pagerNext").unbind('click');
                $('#pagerNext').hover(function() {
                    $(this).css('cursor','default');
                });
            }
            if(1 == 211 || 211 == 0) {
                $("#pagerLast").unbind('click');
                $('#pagerLast').hover(function() {
                    $(this).css('cursor','default');
                });
            }
        });
        function GoToPage(page) {
            $("#pageNumber").val(page);
    CollectAuctionObjectsFilters();
            $("#dvPager").parent("form").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction on how to approach this. Thank you.

Comment: ThunderMind has provided a correct answer but if you want us to help with a solution to a specific website you should give us an url.

Comment: @terrain inconnu, what is the reaction/response of website when you call for the page that doesn't exist ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The problem lies within my code, i.e. as it currently stands, the program does not loop through the page numbers. Instead of 'looping through i and pass this to the FormRequest, then retrieve page i and then callback after_post' the program immediately loops through all i's up to 209 and only then (i.e. at i=209) performs the other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are normally two approaches to solve this problem,

First,

Use `splash` to render the javascript.

Second,

Find the `network call` when you press `next`, and then follow that call to extract desired data.

Comment: That's great, will explore this ansatz and see if I can make this work. My original idea was that the pagination issue could be solved via Scrapy's request & response method vs the HTML form.

Comment: then try finding the `network call` and that is actually the best solution :) Because Splash cause speed issues.

Comment: I managed to make some progress by just using Scrapy's FormRequest but can't iterate through all pages (i.e. looping through the parameter "i" only returns the last page). Code:                                                                                                            
    `for i in range (1, 210):
        formdata = {'pageNumber': str(i)}      
        def parse(self, response):
            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata=self.formdata,
                            callback=self.after_post)`

Comment: can you provide the web link ? that might help to better understand the problem.

Comment: I edited the question in order to reflect the progress so far and also better articulate the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial & error I figured out that the iteration has to be inside the 'def parse' part. Here is the solution:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for i in range (1, 210):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata ={
                    'pageNumber': str(i)
                    },
                callback = self.after_post
            )

    def after_post(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.AL'):
            yield{
                'link': link.css('div.AL').extract()
            }
```

Comment: yes, and for multiple returns, `yield` is used, while you were using return command.